# geth: does --gcmode=archive require --syncmode=full?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, archive-node

I can't seem to find a straight answer to this question since snap is relatively new.

I'm currently running geth 1.10.3 with `--syncmode snap` and `--gcmode archive`, but i'm beginning to think that archive only truly works with syncmode=full?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that to get a truly archive node (all states since genesis) you need to run `--syncmode=full` as it reads the imported block and verifies all transactions.

On the other hand, `snap` will just download the blocks and only when it reaches the current tip it switches to full and starts generating states.

So running `--syncmode snap` and `--gcmode archive` will get you states (archive node) only when it reaches the current tip.